# Tips to make reverse engineering a C shared library more difficult

Tags: c, obfuscation, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I am interested in precautionary measures you could take to make reverse engineering a C shared library more difficult

It seems that it is impossible to prevent entirely but you can take steps that might make it take longer and therefore be less attractive/more costly to do

Things like code obfuscation, compiler optimisation options compiler debug flags etc. (I would be specifically interested in the gcc compiler)

Also interested in any thoughts on the relative difficulty of reverse engineering a  ~5KLOC C shared library  (.so size of ~200kb) in terms of $ or man hours etc.

Comment: The question is more like 'What do you want to hide?'. DRM measures are difficult to hide, because they boil down to a if statement 'if not licensed then warn'. Actual algorithms are very difficult to reverse engineer due to the sheer size and complexity and may be viewed as 'not reverse engineer-able' outside of months of work.

Comment: The question you should ask is, "who actually cares enough to decompile my code and try to reverse engineer it?" You'll find the answer is typically, "nobody". Even better, you can try all you want but you won't stop people who really do want to reverse engineer your code. Spend your time and effort on improving your product instead.

Comment: Definitely _not_ code obfuscation.

Comment: @Hiett I think I was thrown on the wrong track by your “code obfuscation” mention. You do not intend to distribute your library as obfuscated source code, do you? (If you did I would have an answer for you.)

Comment: @PascalCuoq i was wondering (possibly very naively) if code obfuscation prior to compilation would have any effect on the subsequent difficulty of reverse-engineering the resulting shared library binary (just to reiterate I am specifically talking about C code)

Comment: @Christopher what i would want to hide is the algorithms - and would be interested in ball-park figures for timescales required to reverse-engineer, e.g would it take man-years for a few k of machine code or, say, with a copy of hex-ray could you do it in an evening?

Comment: @Hiett If you only had a non-optimizing compiler to use, it might help, but it could not do anything worse than an optimizing compiler does. In fact, by making source code patterns less idiomatic, source code obfuscation might even prevent optimization and make the object code easier to reverse-engineer.

Comment: @sixlettervariables potentially 'who cares enough' might be proportional to the difficulty and therefore effort involved in reverse engineering and thats really what I'm trying to get a handle on - I realise all you can do is try to 'slow-down' rather than 'prevent' in this area - it would be great to know what practical steps you can take to achieve this (and of course I should spend as much time as possible on improving my product;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are some tricks that I know of:

- Use `strip` with the `--strip-unneeded` option to remove all symbols except the ones that are needed for relocation (since we're talking about a shared library):

  `strip --strip-unneeded libmylib.so`
- Link with the standard libc *statically*, this results in a bigger library/binary which means more code to go through and also obfuscation since it will be more difficult to separate your functions from the library functions:

  `gcc -static ...`
- Force the compiler to inline small functions, this embeds small functions in your code instead of calling them, so it makes it almost impossible to distinguish between your code and the standard library code.

Having said that, I must add that I've had a binary that used the above measures and I was able to reverse engineer it in a few hours, I started by rebuilding the `symtab` if you're curious, and I'm no reverse engineering guru.

Answer (score 4):

**- No need of code obfuscation (as in C# or Java).**

The name of your internal variables and functions do not exist in the object code.

However the name of your exported functions will still appear in clear in the shared object file. This sounds reasonable.

**- Better to use `gcc` optimization flags `-O2` or `-O3`.**

Using compiler optimization, object code can largely differ from source code. It is actually very difficult to go back to the original C source code.

However it is always possible to revert engineer at the assembly level. Usually, not all your program is valuable. It will be easier to reverse engineer the interesting portion in assembly rather than the whole program in C.

Comment: Well ... not exactly, but Yes. Assembly can be more structured, with names assigned to machine code blocks of program or data. But apart from that, assembly language matches one for one with machine code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with most common anti-reversing techniques is that they are well-known and there are tools to overcome them. Of course, stripping symbols and obfuscation, is a must have, but this is just about hiding names/symbols.

If you want to make the job for reversers even harder, invent some code manipulation yourself. It can be something really easy, like using a custom calling convention, but this will make all the disassemblers fail to recognize starts and ends of functions.

These kinds of simple tricks will be quite effective, because there won't be an already-made tool to revert the code to the original. You see, for almost every commercial packer or encrypter, there is already a one-click-unpacker.

Answer (score 3):

Not that much. Once you've stripped debug symbols *and* obfuscated all *internal* symbols (not external ones because the clients of the library need a symbol to link to), theres not much you can do. Assembly disassembly is very easy because of the 1-1 mapping of instructions to opcodes. On this other hand, it is very difficult to understand compiler generated assembly code, as it is full of bizarre optimizations and efficiency tricks.

On that note, turning GCC up to highest optimization is probably one of the best obfuscation tricks you can use.

Considering modern computing power, the disassembly itself won't take that long, and at that point it takes a human to decipher it.

Just curious though: What is so important to not have reverse engineered? The encryption and security that keeps things like financial data safe are mostly open source. Or is this a proprietary software protection thing?

Comment: and assembly disassembly being translation from assembly code to machine code and vice versa?

Comment: Assembly disassembly is translation from machine code to assembly source.

Comment: re why - all down to bureaucratic red-tape devised by non software engineers of course ;-) ours is not to reason why but to fill in forms and risk assessments...

Answer (score 0):

Mix your code with switch/case obfuscation (make it nonlinear).

Use C++ templates to encrypt variables/strings at the compilation time. It's possible to encapsulate integer types in double type to make the reversing a little bit harder.

Insert assembly obfuscation macros between the real code (jmp x, db 0E8h, x: etc.)

Use BOOST ;) it really makes reverse engineering a pain the the ... ;)