# private key protection in c++ shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, reverse-engineering

I am building a C++ shared Library which will be used to decrypt the encrypted file using a symmetric cryptographic Algorithm.

My question is how should I store my private key in library. If I'll hardcode it, then tools like radare2 or strings utility can easily find out the private key.

so what is the best way to protect my private key?

Note: I know attacker with enough knowledge will be able to extract the key no matter how we store it. But I want to make that process difficult and time consuming.

Comment: The nice thing about obfuscation is that it's security through obscurity, so it never works and the reverse engineer always wins. In a way you can never fail the task since there was never an option to win. Just a thought: Link **statically** against a decryption library to encrypt the private key. Maybe bury the key to that encryption behind some ROT13 encryption. Then follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679551/obfuscating-c-shared-library) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496735/tips-to-make-reverse-engineering-a-c-shared-library-more-difficult)

Comment: A library with a hardcoded encryption key seems like an odd thing to do. **What are you really trying to do?** by which a pre-compiled library is a solution?  What's the point of encrypting the file if all the attacker needs to do is use your library?

Comment: You will be very disappointed to find out that all your obfuscation efforts are useless if anybody can attach a debugger to your library and step through until they find the call to the decrypt function, with the key sitting in memory right there. Actually, I have an even dumber idea: just give your library a large file to process and take a memory dump while it is busy. The key will be either sitting on the stack or referenced from a pointer on the stack. Trivial.

Comment: @selbie the library basically has something to do with device integrity and may be used in android app. And encrypted file has data which will prevent attacker from detaching library from app. 
what do you suggest how should I decrypt the file without putting the key in the library?

Comment: @Homer512 thanks for the reply! I'll try to implement your suggestion

Comment: @Botje  Thank you for the information. I know it is not possible to 100% protect the credentials within the binary but I am asking suggestions about how to make it difficult and time consuming i.e. attacker has to put in lots of efforts

Comment: I just demonstrated they do not need to make _any_ effort if they can run your decryption routines.

Comment: An attacker can also just wait until they know the app decrypted the file, then dump the memory. In a C/C++ app, they just need to search the memory allocator metadata for an allocation of the correct size. Should be simple with a rooted phone. If you really want to keep stuff secret, put it into a hardware device or on a server; not a client device

Comment: If you are writing a library, just push the key storage responsibility to the user. No user serious about security will use a library with hardcoded credentials anyway.

Comment: @Quimby my problem is that my file is encrypted using a tool & then will be pushed into the apk along with the RSA encrypted secret key.

How can I handle this scenario??

Comment: @Ghostop  Botje is right, the design is inherently unsafe, is it really unchangeable? You mentioned device integrity, that is what TPM is for because it is far from trivial to do correctly. "encrypted file has data which will prevent attacker from detaching library from app" are you really really sure this is true? Android devices have fTPMs, can you perhaps leverage it somehow? I do not have experience with android API and what it offers but I would assume you are not the first application needing to verify its integrity.

Comment: @Quimby Thank you for the reply! I know android provides TEE (Trusted Execution environment) but in my case encryption is not done at my end (i.e not in the library) that means key is generated before hand so I do not think TEE will help me in this case.